# Play/Pause/Stop MP3 audio file | (Visual) C++

Tags: c++, windows, audio, visual-c++, mp3

I want to try and make an MP3 player for Windows. I searched for a function to play audio and found `PlaySound()` and `mciSendString()`, from my "research" I found that PlaySound() is only for `.wav` files, but, for now at least, I want `.mp3`. I tried `mciSendString()`, if in the **play** command, at the end of string I have the parameter **"wait"**(`mciSendString("play audio.mp3 wait", NULL, 0, 0)`) then the audio plays fine, but, I can't stop it, I will have to wait(what a surprise) for the audio to end, I found that the **wait** parameter does that(again, what a surprise). I tried then something like that:

```
while (!_kbhit()){ //as long as I don't press something
    mciSendString("play audio.mp3", NULL, 0, 0); //without the wait
}
```

I thought that this function might have some sort of pointer that points to where exactly we are in the audio, how much of it we have heard, and with each execution of the command with the same audio, the pointer going, little by little, to the end, to the last "element" of the `.mp3` file(**note:** I don't have the slightest idea how `mp3` files and reading from them works)

I seached on the Internet for an example of proper use of `mciSendString()`, but I couldn't find any clear example/answer or something that works for me, for example, many were saying that still, without the **wait** it would work, but it didn't. So, here I am now.

**What I'm asking:** a clear example(code if possible) on how to use `mciSendString` or other function(s) to do the same thing.

---

Thank you for listening(reading actually) my problem.

Comment: this all is prehistoric/newbie .  you need  `wave* ` stuff like `waveOutWrite()`

Comment: see A Programmer's Guide to Sound by Tim Kientzle. no mp3 there but book is not bad

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин is `wave*` the same with `.wav`? if yes, then, why is `.mp3` prehistoric, all the music I have in my computer/phone is `.mp3`, `.wav`, from what I know is far more expensive in space, yes, it sounds better, but I dont think it is worth, also there are out there so many mp3 players, why can't I do mine?

Comment: about `PlaySound()` and this stuff

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин is this book from 1998? ty for the recommendetion, if that's it I will give it a try, if not then please tell me the year it came out or something that will help me identify it

Comment: you found something on github and copy-paste it. For anything else you need to convert mp3 to pack of pcm's first. it's not easy and mpeg2 will be not bad to start with. it worth if you wanna make own library for mp3 decoding. If you don't you'll get pcm array from lib you can find and still need to play pcm's received. Part of this book is about that. you can use say `lame` lib as decoder